# How to sum the total sum from two other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have this a df with some columns. I could get the total sum of column ['Profit'] and ['Commission']. I am trying to get a new column ['Net Profit'] of the total sum from column ['Profit'] and ['Commission'] but I could get only a concatenation of lists or a sum of each row in the column

```
    gross_profit = [df['Profit'].sum()]
    commissions = [df['Commission'].sum()]
```

What I tried:

```
    df['net_profit'] = df['Profit'] + df['Commission']
    df['net_profit'] = df['Profit'].sum() + df['Commission'].sum()
```

By the way, how one can get a total sum of an Excel column in Python without going through Pandas?

Thank you.

Comment: Should all rows of the `df['net_profit']` column have have the same value? Or do you just want to know the total sum and not store it in the data frame?

Comment: @Gilad only the total sum from the already calculated total sum of the other two columns

Comment: then why not just: `somevar = df['Profit'].sum() + df['Commission'].sum()`?

Comment: @Gilad yes, you are right. I think I tried also that one but somehow I didn't consider it. Can you do this without going through a pandas dataframe, just python?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is to create a new column

```
df['net_profit'] = df['Profit'] + df['Comission']

df_describe = df.describe()
```

The `df_describe` data frame will have the sum as an entry for the column 'net_profit'. It will additionally have other statistics like mean, min, max, and percentiles.

Comment: thanks for the reply. The df['net_profit'] = df['Profit'] + df['Comission']
is what I wrote in my question and it sums row values whereas I'd like to have the total sum of the other two columns.

Comment: You need to create a new data frame (here df_describe). Because I does not make sense to have an aggregated value in all rows (this is redundant). Hence, create a new data frame and use the describe() function. If you inspect df_describe with df_describe.head() you should see your desired result.

Comment: try this: `df["new_column"] = df[["column1","column2"]].sum().sum()`

Comment: @Machine I tried, but I don't get the correct sum, and I would like only the sum printed not all the stats describe() gives.

Comment: @RakeshV thanks, yes it gives the correct sum but it prints in all the rows.

Comment: @Steven: Remember that df_describe is a normal data frame. You can select its columns with `df_describe.loc[rows, columns]` e.g. `df_describe.loc[['mean'], ['net_profit']]`will give you only the row of the mean for the column net_profit.